# Keras Custom Layer Error (Operation IsVariableInitialized has been marked as not fetchable)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a custom Keras layer on a toy dataset, and am having issues. At a high level, I want to create an "Input Gate" layer, which would have trainable weights to turn each column of input on or off. So I'm starting with just trying to multiply the inputs by a sigmoid'd version of the learned weights. My code is as follows:

```
### This is my custom layer
class InputGate(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InputGate, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name='input_gate',
                                      shape=input_shape[1:],
                                      initializer='random_uniform',
                                      trainable=True)

        super(InputGate, self).build(input_shape)  # Be sure to call this somewhere!

    def call(self, inputs):
        gate_amount = K.sigmoid(self.kernel)
        return inputs * gate_amount

    def get_config(self):
        config = {}
        base_config = super(InputGate, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

def create_linear_model(x, y, num_noise_vars = 0, reg_strength=0):
    new_x = get_x_with_noise(x, num_noise_vars=num_noise_vars)
    model = Sequential([
        InputGate(input_shape=(1+num_noise_vars,)),
        Dense(1, kernel_regularizer=l2(reg_strength))
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="mse")
    model.optimizer.lr = 0.001
    return {"model": model, "new_x": new_x}

def get_x_with_noise(x, num_noise_vars):
    noise_vars = []
    for noise_var in range(num_noise_vars):
        noise_vars.append(np.random.random(len(x)))
    noise_vars.append(x)
    x_with_noise = noise_vars
    new_x = np.array(list(zip(*x_with_noise)))
    return new_x

x = np.random.random(500)
y = (x * 3) + 10
num_noise_vars = 5
info = create_linear_model(x, y, num_noise_vars=num_noise_vars)
model = info["model"]
new_x = info["new_x"]
results = model.fit(new_x, y, epochs=num_epochs, verbose=0)
```

And then I get the following error:
`ValueError: Operation 'input_gate_14/IsVariableInitialized' has been marked as not fetchable.`

This layer is mostly taken from the docs(https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/). I'm using Keras 2.0.9, with Tensorflow backend on a CPU (Macbook Air).

This layer seems as simple as can be, and googling the error leads me to discussions that don't seem relevant. Anyone have ideas of what's causing this?

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!